# Does Microsoft POWER BI work in-house without relying on cloud technology? How is it done?

Tags: powerbi

Does **Microsoft POWER BI** work in-house without relying on cloud technology? How is it done?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way: Download Power BI Desktop. Create .pbix documents. Share as you would an Excel workbook.

Use on-premises or external data sources that you have access to. For example, access a SQL Server database using Windows integrated security if so configured; or use the "page scraping" feature to pull a table off of a web page. The data is stored in the .pbix and can be manually refreshed.

This is obviously not a very sophisticated or well-managed approach but does have some advantages.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from @Tom's answer, here's the roadmap including on-prem PowerBI that MS published last year.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2015/10/29/microsoft-business-intelligence-our-reporting-roadmap/

The short version is that there appears to be an intention of adding this to SSRS in a future release. But for now, the option we use is to share PowerBI workbooks using PowerBI desktop as @Tom describes.